# Docker .env numeric variable evaluation

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I wrote my .env file:

```
LOGSTASH_TCP_IP=192.168.0.65
LOGSTASH_TCP_PORT=5000
```

In my docker-compose I wrote:

```
my-app:
    image: my-app
    environment:
      - LOGSTASH_TCP_IP=$LOGSTASH_TCP_IP
      - LOGSTASH_TCP_PORT=$LOGSTASH_TCP_PORT
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      config:
        condition: service_healthy
    ports:
      - 8010:8010
```

this approach does not work because LOGSTASH_TCP_PORT is evaluated with single quotes: '5000'

I also verified this anomaly with the command `docker-compose config`

Is there a solution to evaluate the number correctly?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  What's going wrong?  Environment variable values are always strings; the syntax you have looks correct, and should set the environment variable `LOGSTASH_TCP_PORT` to the string `5000`.

Comment: in the logback.xml of my application I set:

<appender name = "STASH" class = "net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender">
         <destination> ${logstash.tcp.ip}: ${logstash.tcp.port} </ destination>

but an address of the type 192.168.0.65:'5000'  is not correctly evaluated because of the quotes